# Merge two CSV files using bash/python

Tags: python, bash, shell, csv, export-to-csv

I have two CSV files that I need help mapping/merging:

CSV File1:

```
"ID","Name","Flavor"
"45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582","test1","m1.medium"
"83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5","test2","m1.tiny"
"ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769","test3","m1.medium"
```

CSV File2:

```
"Name","RAM","Disk","VCPUs"
"m1.medium",4096,40,2
"m1.xlarge",16384,160,8
"m1.tiny",128,1,1
```

The ideal output would be:

```
"ID","Name","Flavor","RAM","Disk","VCPUs"
"45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582","test1","m1.medium",4096,40,2
"83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5","test2","m1.tiny",128,1,1
"ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769","test3","m1.medium",4096,40,2
```

Note that `Flavor` in CSV File 1 and `Name` in CSV File 2 are the same. The difference in name is a result of the different tool being used to pull the info.

Also note, CSV File2 has a `flavor/name` `m1.xlarge`. As detailed above, if the `m1.xlarge` `flavor/name` is not found in CSV File1 it should be discarded from the consolidated output.

I've been at this all day with mixed results. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you haven't specified the operation other than 'mapping/merging'. Do you simply search CSV2 for the first(?) occurrence of a line that also has "m1.medium"?  Or for the last? Is the first field in CSV2 unique? Etc. I suppose specifying the 'mapping/merging' operation to /yourself/ is at least 50% of the job done.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please be more specific. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Javier do you want the CSVs joined on the Name/Flavor columns or just merge all the columns into one file keeping the rows where they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you'll have to play around with the quoting options to see what you like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

by_name = {}
with open('b.csv') as b:
    for row in csv.DictReader(b):
        name = row.pop('Name')
        by_name[name] = row

with open('c.csv', 'w') as c:
    w = csv.DictWriter(c, ['ID', 'Name', 'Flavor', 'RAM', 'Disk', 'VCPUs'])
    w.writeheader()

    with open('a.csv') as a:
        for row in csv.DictReader(a):
            try:
                match = by_name[row['Flavor']]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            row.update(match)

            w.writerow(row)
```

Output:

```
ID,Name,Flavor,RAM,Disk,VCPUs
45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582,test1,m1.medium,4096,40,2
83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5,test2,m1.tiny,128,1,1
ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769,test3,m1.medium,4096,40,2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v hdr='"ID","Name","Flavor","RAM","Disk","VCPUs"' 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=","
   print hdr
}
NR == FNR {
   a[$1] = $2 FS $3 FS $4
   next
}
$3 in a {
   print $0, a[$3]
}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

```
"ID","Name","Flavor","RAM","Disk","VCPUs"
"45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582","test1","m1.medium",4096,40,2
"83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5","test2","m1.tiny",128,1,1
"ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769","test3","m1.medium",4096,40,2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and you want to match up rows in the first file based on the string in the `Flavor` column with the rows that have that value in the `Name` column in the second csv, then this is quite easy to do with [`xsv`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) (which you'll likely need to [install first](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv#installation)):

```
$ xsv join "Flavor" file1.csv "Name" file2.csv
ID,Name,Flavor,Name,RAM,Disk,VCPUs
45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582,test1,m1.medium,m1.medium,4096,40,2
83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5,test2,m1.tiny,m1.tiny,128,1,1
ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769,test3,m1.medium,m1.medium,4096,40,2
```

You'll have to also remove the duplicate `Name` column, which you can do with `xsv` again:

```
$ xsv join "Flavor" file1.csv "Name" file2.csv | xsv select ID,Name,Flavor,RAM,Disk,VCPUs
ID,Name,Flavor,RAM,Disk,VCPUs
45fc754d-6a9b-4bde-b7ad-be91ae60f582,test1,m1.medium,4096,40,2
83dbc739-e436-4c9f-a561-c5b40a3a6da5,test2,m1.tiny,128,1,1
ef68fcf3-f624-416d-a59b-bb8f1aa2a769,test3,m1.medium,4096,40,2
```